# What does BHP@rpm mean?

Tags: engine, terminology

In my car's specs sheet I noticed:
Power (BHP@rpm): 117@6600

What does BHP@rpm mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brake Horse Power at 6600 RPM.

BHP is measured at the crankshaft. 
[This](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8057/what-is-the-meaning-of-bhp-and-torque-in-bikes-or-cars) post gives a nice description of how the BHP is calculated.